# How can i get CSV column values in php

Tags: php, csv

I have an excel file suppose with column value "A B" what i want is to separate the values after the first space i.e A in another column and B in other.
I used PHPEXCEL

```
<?php
 class SampleReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
    // Read rows 1 to 10 and columns A to C only
    if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 7) {
       if (in_array($column,range('A','C'))) {
         return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What you tried so far ...?

Comment: @yash i used phpexcel to read the csv file

Comment: PHPExcel can't magically know that you're using a space as a separator in a csv file, you have to tell it what separator you're using.... https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/05-Reader-Options.md#pipe-or-tab-separated-value-files

Comment: Are you trying to read the csv? In that case I think phpexcel is overkill. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("abc.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {        
        $username =  $data[0];
        $usernames  = explode(' ', $email);
        print($usernames[1]).'<br />';

}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```